# QCombobox - hide first item on drop-down

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, usability, qcombobox

Hello fellow developers!

I want to realize a "Action" QCombobox where the different options trigger an action instead of choosing an option. The combobox says something like "Add Property" and when the user clicks it, he gets the different properties to choose from. If the user clicks one of them, it is added to -whateverdoesntmatter-. The combobox than switches back to it's original state.

The problem is, that the first entry "Add Property" is shown on the combobox's drop down, causing a little bit of confusion for the user since it is not really an action.

Normal state:

```
[Add Property]
```

Drop-down state:

```
[Add Property]
Add Property
Length
Width
etc ...
```

Therefore, I want to hide the first option as soon as the combobox drops down to achieve this behavior:

```
[Add Property]
Length
Width
etc ...
```

I have already tried with subclassing the combobox and overwriting showPopUp() and hidePopUp() - but I could not figure out how to get my intended behavior.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You need to work with model of combobox.

Comment: First, do you *really* need a `QComboBox`? Maybe you're better/easier off using a `QToolBar` with drop-down tool buttons. Or just a `QToolButton` with a `QMenu` associated.

Comment: @SaZ I tried to do this when I overwrote showPopUp() and hidePopUp() but maybe I missed something ... I tried to "take" the first QabstractItem and than add it again on hide. Maybe I am missing some model functionality though.

Comment: @Kamaji Good idea, I will try it out. I did not know the ToolButton before, but it seems like the opoupMode "MenuButtonPopUp" is going into the direction I want.

Comment: @Kamaji okay, this worked perfectly. If you want to, you can add this as answer and I mark it as the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't absolutely need a `QComboBox` you might be better/easier off using a `QToolButton` with a `QMenu` associated and then set the button's `popupMode` to an appropriate value.

You may even use a `QToolBar`. Simply add a `QAction` with your desired label (like *Add Property*), associate the menu to it via `QAction::setMenu` and at it to the toolbar. The toolbar will automatically create the tool buttons itself.

To access the `popupMode` property you can use `QToolBar::widgetForAction` and cast it to a `QToolButton`.